# Copying highlighted text in any place works correctly only first time

Tags: java

By design, the buffer is placed in the *rawData* field. The selected text is placed in the buffer, after which it should be displayed in the notification area and then *rawData* place back to the buffer. In my case, copying correctly works only the first time. I'm using [external library](https://github.com/kristian/system-hook) for global keylistener. You can check all the code [here](https://github.com/SweetSquid/translation). To start you need to select text and press Alt+X.

```
GlobalKeyboardHook keyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(true); // use false here to switch to hook instead of raw input

    keyboardHook.addKeyListener(new GlobalKeyAdapter() { //add key listener
        @Override public void keyPressed(GlobalKeyEvent event) {
            if (event.isMenuPressed() && event.getVirtualKeyCode()!=0x58){ //0x58 equals X key  (Runs when alt+х pressed)
                try {
                    rawData = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); //get data raw data from clipboard
                    System.out.println("What was in clipboard:  " + rawData);
                    String kek = Copy.getCopy(); //get copied data
                    System.out.println("What was copied:  " + kek);
                    Notification.runNotification(kek); //start notification
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(rawData), null); //returning raw data
                    System.out.println("What came into clipboard: " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw  new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

static String getCopy() throws IOException, UnsupportedFlavorException {
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mykyta, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could describe your problem in a little more detail. Namely: it only works correctly the first time, so what does it do after that? What have you tried so far to fix the problem? What part of the code (if any) do you think is causing the problem?

Comment: each next time the selected text is not copied, it is simply taken from the buffer. At first, I thought the problem was copying the text using the Robot class. After some experimentation, I came to the conclusion that the problem is related to the library. Since keyListener works after any keystroke, I thought that ctrl+c emulation affects this, but it isn’t. All the code that contains in method keyPressed work correctly, if you run without a library (just select the text and run the program each time)